# ORACLE SQL - How can I find the interval between the previous resign date and join date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to find the number of months it takes for the teacher to join the school again i.e. interval between resign date of the previous row and join date of the current row.

```
teacher_id  row_num  teacher_type join_dt     resign_dt   
23            1         PT        2015-01-04  2017-08-10  
4             1         PT        2013-02-01  2013-03-15  
4             2         FT        2013-05-20  2015-12-09
4             3         FT        2016-07-11  2017-01-03
13            1         PT        2017-03-22  2018-06-04
10            1         FT        2017-10-23  2018-12-11
11            1         FT        2019-05-22  2019-11-02
```

Expected results:

```
teacher_id  row_num  teacher_type join_dt     resign_dt    mth_interval
23            1         PT        2015-01-04  2017-08-10   0
4             1         PT        2013-02-01  2013-03-15   0
4             2         FT        2013-05-20  2015-12-09   2
4             3         FT        2016-07-11  2017-01-03   7
13            1         PT        2017-03-22  2018-06-04   0
10            1         FT        2017-10-23  2018-12-11   0
11            1         FT        2019-05-22  2019-11-02   0
```

Over here, `mth_interval` is 0 for `teacher_id` 23 because she only joined once. On the other hand, teacher_id 4 has joined as a Part Timer once, resigned and re-joined again as a Full timer twice. Therefore, `mth_interval` is 2 and 7 respectively for the two times she re-joined.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you all!! :-)

Comment: Your join and resign dates do not match month boundaries, and the differences are not a round number of months (for example from 15 March to 20 May). So, what do you **really** need in the output? A number of months, as reported by the function `months_between`, where the answer may look like 1.193028? Do you need to truncate (round down) each such number? Round it (meaning round down or up, as the case may be)? Note that if in the end you will compute summary statistics, like **average** months to re-join, then it makes absolutely no sense to round the individual intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LAG()` analytical function. For example:

```
select
  teacher_id, row_num, teacher_type, join_dt, resign_dt,
  months_between(join_t, prev_resign) as mth_interval
from (
  select teacher_id, row_num, teacher_type, join_dt, resign_dt,
    lag(resign_dt) over(partition by teacher_id order by join_dt) as prev_resign 
  from t
) x
```

Comment: You can't select * and something else in the same `SELECT` clause. You must select 't.*` or similar.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, it's fixed This seems to be a "feature" of Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    T.*,
    COALESCE(MONTHS_BETWEEN(T.JOIN_DT,(LAG(T.RESIGN_DT) OVER(
        PARTITION BY T.TEACHER_ID
        ORDER BY
            T.JOIN_DT
    ))), 0) AS MTH_INTERVAL
FROM
    T;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self-join in this case:

```
SELECT T.*,
       NVL(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(T.JOIN_DT, T1.RESIGN_DT)), 0) AS MTH_INTERVAL
  FROM T
  LEFT OUTER JOIN T T1
    ON T1.TEACHER_ID = T.TEACHER_ID AND
       T1.ROW_NUM = T.ROW_NUM - 1
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7102dfc42720903533c1a81e19169c60)

Comment: Analytic functions were created with the stated purpose of avoiding self-joins in such problems. `LEAD()` or `LAG()` is a better approach than a self-join.